# Sharing resources between two independent Openstack cloud setups

Tags: openstack

Is there any possibility to share resources from one openstack cloud to another similar one with different resource pools.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CloudFerry:[Github Link](https://github.com/MirantisWorkloadMobility/CloudFerry)

CloudFerry is a tool for resources and workloads migration between two OpenStack clouds.

Another Tool Stack2Stack: [Github Link](https://github.com/ggillies/stack2stack)

stack2stack is a simple python script to aid data migration from one Openstack cloud to another through use of the APIs. It aims to cleanly migrate the data keeping as much in sync as possible, up to the limitations of the Openstack APIs themselves. Currently the script migrates

```
Keystone Users
Keystone Tenants
Keystone roles
Keystone Tenant Memberships
Glance Images
Networks from nova networking to neutron
Security groups from nova networking to neutron
```